# Can I cross compile my AS3 code or Flex project to native C++?

Tags: c++, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I would like to tak emy existing AS3 or Flex project and compile it to run on native C++ code.  Is there a way to do this?  What sort of solutions exist?  I do not want to change my AS3 code.

Comment: what you're asking for doesn't make sense. A program doesn't "run on native C++ code". A program can be written in C++ or one of many other programming languages, and compiled to a native machine language executable. If you want to compile AS3 to a native executable, C++ has absolutely nothing to do with that.

Comment: sorry for semantics, yes, I want to compile the AS3 to a native executable.  Somewhat like what you can do with Flash Builder for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because of

- absense of dynamic features in C++ (you don't have `Object` and `describeType` equivalent there)
- absense of Flash native types in C++ (String (std::string is not equivalent), display objects and many others)
- absense of language features (event listeners, garbage collection)
- absense of Flex framework equivalent in C++ (there are other good GUI frameworks in C++, but none looks like Flex - because of the reasons above.)

In short, it's *much* easier to write similar program in C++ (using Qt or whatever framework of comparable strength) than write convertor for that.

Comment: I was expecting this, but wasn't entirely sure how some of the other methods were handling this.  i.e. Flash Builder and Scaleform.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

AS3 is a framework operating on prebuilt libraries you would have to replace somehow in your "translated" code. For example, what would you imagine the native code to do, when you do `new Sprite()`?

Haxe doesn't try to find a replacement. It takes different approach in that it lets you reuse bits of the code that would translate easily, but those that don't translate are marked as specific to certain environment. There is, however, an effort in Haxe to come up with API similar to those of Flash display list by using NME graphic engine.

Given your example with the iOS compiler - it, again, compiles against the existing library of native code that provides the functionality of display list, video and audio players and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you can convert it to Haxe (Haxe has extremely AS3 like syntax, only libraries and some language constructs differ) it should provide you with an option of compiling for "native". I've heard it even provides a C++ sourcecode or so I've been told by folks at IRC Haxe room. I could have been trolled for the code part, though he didn't seem like he was trolling...

I'ts not perfect and definitely lacks some more advanced capabilities but it's worth looking at probably.